# How can I optimize the SELECT statement running on an Oracle database?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a SELECT statement in ORACLE:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ds1.endpoint_msisdn)                  multiple30,
       dss1.service,
       dss1.endpoint_provisioning_id,
       dss1.company_scope,
       Nvl(x.subscription_status, dss1.subscription_status) subscription_status
FROM   daily_summary ds1
       join daily_summary ds2
         ON ds1.endpoint_msisdn = ds2.endpoint_msisdn,
       daily_summary_static dss1,
       daily_summary_static dss2,
       (SELECT NULL subscription_status
        FROM   dual
        UNION ALL
        SELECT -2 subscription_status
        FROM   dual) x
WHERE  ds1.summary_ts >= To_date('10-04-2012', 'dd-mm-yyyy') - 30
       AND ds1.summary_ts <= To_date('10-04-2012', 'dd-mm-yyyy')
       AND dss1.last_active >= To_date('10-04-2012', 'dd-mm-yyyy') - 30
       AND dss1.last_active <= To_date('10-04-2012', 'dd-mm-yyyy')
       AND dss2.last_active >= To_date('10-04-2012', 'dd-mm-yyyy') - 30
       AND dss2.last_active <= To_date('10-04-2012', 'dd-mm-yyyy')
       AND dss1.service <> dss2.service
       AND ( dss1.company_scope = 2
              OR dss1.company_scope = 5 )
       AND ( dss2.company_scope = 2
              OR dss2.company_scope = 5 )
       AND dss1.company_scope = dss2.company_scope
       AND ds1.endpoint_noc_id = dss1.endpoint_noc_id
       AND ds1.endpoint_host_id = dss1.endpoint_host_id
       AND ds1.endpoint_instance_id = dss1.endpoint_instance_id
       AND ds2.endpoint_noc_id = dss2.endpoint_noc_id
       AND ds2.endpoint_host_id = dss2.endpoint_host_id
       AND ds2.endpoint_instance_id = dss2.endpoint_instance_id
       AND dss1.endpoint_provisioning_id = dss2.endpoint_provisioning_id
       AND Least(1, ds1.total_actions) = 1
       AND Least(1, ds2.total_actions) = 1
GROUP  BY dss1.service,
          dss1.endpoint_provisioning_id,
          dss1.company_scope,
          Nvl(x.subscription_status, dss1.subscription_status);
```

This query took about 26 minutes to return in my environment, but if I remove the section:

```
dss1.last_active >= to_date('10-04-2012','dd-mm-yyyy') - 30 AND
                   dss1.last_active <= to_date('10-04-2012','dd-mm-yyyy') AND
                    dss2.last_active >= to_date('10-04-2012','dd-mm-yyyy') - 30 AND
                   dss2.last_active <= to_date('10-04-2012','dd-mm-yyyy') AND
```

it only took 20 seconds to run.

We have index on the column last_active, I don't know why the section slow down the performance so much? any ideas?

---

if i run this , it was very fast.

`select * from daily_summary_static where last_active >= to_date('10-04-2012','dd-mm-yyyy') - 30 AND last_active <= to_date('10-04-2012','dd-mm-yyyy');`

---

Explain plan for the statement, i don't see any full table scan here, don't know why it run so slowly:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                               | Name                 | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                        |                      |     1 |   119 |   204   (3)| 00:00:03 |
|   1 |  SORT GROUP BY                          |                      |     1 |   119 |   204   (3)| 00:00:03 |
|   2 |   MERGE JOIN CARTESIAN                  |                      |     1 |   119 |   203   (2)| 00:00:03 |
|*  3 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID          | DAILY_SUMMARY        |     1 |    27 |    11   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |     NESTED LOOPS                        |                      |     1 |   116 |   199   (3)| 00:00:03 |
|*  5 |      HASH JOIN                          |                      |     3 |   267 |   178   (3)| 00:00:03 |
|*  6 |       HASH JOIN                         |                      |     1 |    65 |   140   (2)| 00:00:02 |
|   7 |        TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID      | DAILY_SUMMARY_STATIC |    61 |  1647 |    37   (3)| 00:00:01 |
|   8 |         BITMAP CONVERSION TO ROWIDS     |                      |       |       |            |          |
|   9 |          BITMAP AND                     |                      |       |       |            |          |
|  10 |           BITMAP CONVERSION FROM ROWIDS |                      |       |       |            |          |
|  11 |            SORT ORDER BY                |                      |       |       |            |          |
|* 12 |             INDEX RANGE SCAN            | DSS_LAST_ACTIVE      |   560 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  13 |           BITMAP OR                     |                      |       |       |            |          |
|  14 |            BITMAP CONVERSION FROM ROWIDS|                      |       |       |            |          |
|* 15 |             INDEX RANGE SCAN            | DSS_C_SCOPE_IDX      |   560 |       |    18   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  16 |            BITMAP CONVERSION FROM ROWIDS|                      |       |       |            |          |
|* 17 |             INDEX RANGE SCAN            | DSS_C_SCOPE_IDX      |   560 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  18 |        TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID      | DAILY_SUMMARY        |  1773 | 67374 |   102   (0)| 00:00:02 |
|* 19 |         INDEX RANGE SCAN                | DS_DAILY_ACTIVE_IDX  |  1767 |       |    14   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  20 |       TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID       | DAILY_SUMMARY_STATIC |    61 |  1464 |    37   (3)| 00:00:01 |
|  21 |        BITMAP CONVERSION TO ROWIDS      |                      |       |       |            |          |
|  22 |         BITMAP AND                      |                      |       |       |            |          |
|  23 |          BITMAP CONVERSION FROM ROWIDS  |                      |       |       |            |          |
|  24 |           SORT ORDER BY                 |                      |       |       |            |          |
|* 25 |            INDEX RANGE SCAN             | DSS_LAST_ACTIVE      |   560 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  26 |          BITMAP OR                      |                      |       |       |            |          |
|  27 |           BITMAP CONVERSION FROM ROWIDS |                      |       |       |            |          |
|* 28 |            INDEX RANGE SCAN             | DSS_C_SCOPE_IDX      |   560 |       |    18   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  29 |           BITMAP CONVERSION FROM ROWIDS |                      |       |       |            |          |
|* 30 |            INDEX RANGE SCAN             | DSS_C_SCOPE_IDX      |   560 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 31 |      INDEX RANGE SCAN                   | DS_PKEY              |     8 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  32 |    BUFFER SORT                          |                      |     2 |     6 |   193   (3)| 00:00:03 |
|  33 |     VIEW                                |                      |     2 |     6 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  34 |      UNION-ALL                          |                      |       |       |            |          |
|  35 |       FAST DUAL                         |                      |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  36 |       FAST DUAL                         |                      |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: It still take very long time when i remove the **-30** condition. what confuse me is why the date manipulation on dss was so slow but it was fast when when the date manipulation on ds.? since the records in ds was far more than dss... and we have index on last_active in dss.

Comment: There is no intense date manipulation on those lines since the values you are comparing `last_active` to are static and calculated only once. You say you have an index, but are you sure that the optimizer chooses to use it? Can you add the execution plans for both cases?

Comment: Hi Erkan, the explain plan was add in the original post, this explain is for the "slow" SELECT statement, i don't see any full table scan here, the index range scan happened on index **DSS_LAST_ACTIVE** , don't why it run so slowly.

Comment: As far as I can see the times in the execution plan sums up to less than one minute.

Comment: The plan you posted shows what the optimizer expects. Now it's time to see what actually happened in those 26 minutes. Please do "set serveroutput off", then "alter session set statistics_level = all", then run your query and finally "select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor(null,null,'allstats last'))" and post what you see.

Comment: How many rows do you get after 26 minutes? Optimizer thinks you'll get a small amount, is that accurate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this section actually makes it slower:

```
AND dss1.last_active >= To_date('10-04-2012', 'dd-mm-yyyy') - 30
AND dss1.last_active <= To_date('10-04-2012', 'dd-mm-yyyy')
AND dss2.last_active >= To_date('10-04-2012', 'dd-mm-yyyy') - 30
AND dss2.last_active <= To_date('10-04-2012', 'dd-mm-yyyy')
```

it seems likely to me that the index on `last_active` is used when it shouldn't, i.e. it prevents using another, more useful index. My bet is on another index that would be used for joining dss1 and dss2, but in fact it doesn't really matter.

Therefore, I propose to disable index usage by deliberately changing the block like this so the query optimizer can no longer use the index:

```
AND (dss1.last_active+0) >= To_date('10-04-2012', 'dd-mm-yyyy') - 30
AND (dss1.last_active+0) <= To_date('10-04-2012', 'dd-mm-yyyy')
AND (dss2.last_active+0) >= To_date('10-04-2012', 'dd-mm-yyyy') - 30
AND (dss2.last_active+0) <= To_date('10-04-2012', 'dd-mm-yyyy')
```

Comment: I also think that use of index might be the cause, we could also use NO_INDEX hint to accomplish that.

Comment: Thanks ammoQ. this really helps. I changed the sql like you suggested, it  works! it finished in 20 seconds. One question is: how this Index prevent using other index?

Comment: Your statictics on your tables might be out of date.

Comment: Elvis: If you have more than one index on a table that could be used for the query, the query optimizer chooses (at most) one of them to access the table. In some cases, like yours, the chosen index is not really the best one.

Comment: Hi ammoQ, One question is, from the explain plan at the original post, it didn't have any full table access, why it was so more slower than your version (with last_active index disabled) which has full table access on dss?

Comment: @ElvisLou: Without the actual execution plan of the modified statement, it's really hard  to tell.